# SectionList - Get Current Sticky Header

Tags: reactjs, listview, react-native

I'm currently having a SectionList with stickyheaders enabled, which works perfectly fine. The problem is that I have not yet been able to retrieve the current stuck header so that I can manipulate it.

I want to have a bottom shadow on the sticky header, but ONLY the active one, therefor I need to have some kind of way of knowing which is active, as I havn't been able to figure out another solution for this.

I would really appreciate some help and suggestions here :)

Comment: Can you add a class to the active one so that you can style it with css?

Comment: The problem is that i cannot retrieve the active one

Comment: did you solve it?if yes please write a solution @DanielWinkel-Pedersen